# react persist Uncaught TypeError: getDefaultMiddleware is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am developing an application with reactjs and I am using redux as my state management tool.

I want to use redux-persist to persist the data that I fetch from the server

but I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: getDefaultMiddleware is not a function
```

This is my code:

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import userReducer from './UserSlice'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
```

store.js

```
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'



const rootReducer = combineReducers({user: userReducer})
This is where I create the persist config

const persistConfigs = {
  key: 'root',
  version: 1,
  storage,
}
```

Here is where I used the persist config

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfigs, rootReducer)

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    reducer: persistReducer,  
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
  },
})

export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be:

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistReducer,  
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
})
```

You have all options nested into the key `reducer`, Following the docs seems this is not correct

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { // <---- Remove this
    reducer: persistReducer,  
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
  },
})
```